# Is there a way to prevent stopping the audio in Spark AR on recording without disable the microphone?

Tags: android, spark-ar-studio

In my current project I have an Audio file which plays all the time. As soon as I click the record button the audio stops. When I disable the microphone it works but I actually want to record my own voice (like a karaoke) This Problem only occurs only on Android.
Is there any hack to fix this Problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just worked on a filter where I had to build a karaoke style gameplay, what I noticed was Spark does not like playing audio AND recording on mic as it probably causes weird artifacting if not implemented properly. It seems like something that will be added line.

Possible fixes to get your filter working for now, add instructions to use the filter with headphones, connecting to an external audio device will let you play audio and record using the mic at the same time. This works on android, not on iOS. You have to give players visual cues to sing along or whatever your objective maybe.

Hope this is sorted out and fixed in the coming updates, really handicaps the kind of experiences possible on the platform.

Hope this helped.